# Why does my ng-repeat filter include IDs from the wrong objects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When using `ng-repeat` on my items I'm trying to filter by their `id` property, but I'm getting matches for things like `id: 14` matches my filter of `id: 4`

javascript:

```
function listCtrl(){
  var vm = this;

  vm.list = [ 
    { id: 15, display: "15"},
    { id: 5, display: "5"},
    { id: 4, display: "4"},
    { id: 14, display: "14"},
    { id: 44, display: "44"}
  ];

  vm.base = [
    { id: 15 },
    { id: 5 },
    { id: 14 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: "4"} // string based
  ];
}
```

html:

```
  <div ng-repeat="base in vm.base">
    <h3>{{ base.id }}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="filtered in vm.list | filter: {id: base.id}">
      Matched: {{ filtered.id }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Output:

```
15    
Matched: 15

5    
Matched: 15
Matched: 5

14
Matched: 14

4    
Matched: 4
Matched: 14
Matched: 44

4    
Matched: 4
Matched: 14
Matched: 44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the sub-string comparison done by default, you need to turn on "strict" mode by adding `:true` to the end of your filter.

```
<div ng-repeat="filtered in vm.list | filter: {id: base.id}">
```

Into

```
<div ng-repeat="filtered in vm.list | filter: {id: base.id} : true">
```

Here is a quick plunker to show both side by side. Notice that the "4" no longer matches any since its a string and the others Ids are numbers!

http://plnkr.co/edit/lzIUxCU9qgOjnWN9JbWz?p=preview

You can learn more about the 3rd (**comparator**) parameter for filter here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter